# Woocommerce recently viewed Products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I have created a recently viewed script which generated a shortcode which I then inserted into my home page.

The script is designed so that people who may have visited my website and left, once they come back can see instantly what products they had been viewing on their last visit.

I have placed the shortcode `[woocommerce_recently_viewed_products]`

and have generated the shortcode using the following script:

```
function rc_woocommerce_recently_viewed_products( $atts, $content = null ) {

// Get shortcode parameters
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    "per_page" => '5'
), $atts));

// Get WooCommerce Global
global $woocommerce;

// Get recently viewed product cookies data
$viewed_products = ! empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ? (array) explode( '|', $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) : array();
$viewed_products = array_filter( array_map( 'absint', $viewed_products ) );

// If no data, quit
if ( empty( $viewed_products ) )
    return __( 'You have not viewed any product yet!', 'rc_wc_rvp' );

// Create the object
ob_start();

wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', implode( '|', $viewed_products ) );
}

// Get products per page
if( !isset( $per_page ) ? $number = 4 : $number = $per_page )

// Create query arguments array
$query_args = array(
                'posts_per_page' => $number, 
                'no_found_rows'  => 1, 
                'post_status'    => 'publish', 
                'post_type'      => 'product', 
                'post__in'       => $viewed_products, 
                'orderby'        => 'rand'
                );

// Add meta_query to query args
$query_args['meta_query'] = array();

// Check products stock status
$query_args['meta_query'][] = $woocommerce->query->stock_status_meta_query();

// Create a new query
$r = new WP_Query($query_args);

// If query return results
if ( $r->have_posts() ) {

    $content = '<ul class="rc_wc_rvp_product_list_widget">';

    // Start the loop
    while ( $r->have_posts()) {
        $r->the_post();
        global $product;

        $content .= '<li>
            <a href="' . get_permalink() . '">
                ' . ( has_post_thumbnail() ? get_the_post_thumbnail( $r->post->ID, 'shop_thumbnail' ) : woocommerce_placeholder_img( 'shop_thumbnail' ) ) . ' ' . get_the_title() . '
            </a> ' . $product->get_price_html() . '
        </li>';
    }

    $content .= '</ul>';

}

// Get clean object
$content .= ob_get_clean();

// Return whole content
return $content;
}

// Register the shortcode
add_shortcode("woocommerce_recently_viewed_products", 
"rc_woocommerce_recently_viewed_products");
```

Everything seems to have registered. However,when I test this myself. I view a few products, go back to the homepage where the shortcode is registered and I see the text

> You have not viewed any product yet!

I can not figure out what might be missing in order to register and show the products which I or a potential customer may have viewed.

Comment: The code that set the cookie is missing… could you add it editing your question please?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I had missed the set cookie out. I have tried adding but get the same result, I have updated question

Comment: You need to set the cookie when the is_product() condition is true.

Comment: @AndrewSchultz so the code appears right, just in the wrong order?  I have tried moving the wc_setcookie() but still keep getting the same result

Answer (score 7):

Woocommerce only save the recently viewed cookie IF woocommerce_recently_viewed_products WIDGET is ACTIVE! See code in wc-product-functions.php wc_track_product_view() function.

Code to save the cookie always in functions.php:

```
/**
 * Track product views. Always.
 */
function wc_track_product_view_always() {
    if ( ! is_singular( 'product' ) /* xnagyg: remove this condition to run: || ! is_active_widget( false, false, 'woocommerce_recently_viewed_products', true )*/ ) {
        return;
    }

    global $post;

    if ( empty( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ) { // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
        $viewed_products = array();
    } else {
        $viewed_products = wp_parse_id_list( (array) explode( '|', wp_unslash( $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'] ) ) ); // @codingStandardsIgnoreLine.
    }

    // Unset if already in viewed products list.
    $keys = array_flip( $viewed_products );

    if ( isset( $keys[ $post->ID ] ) ) {
        unset( $viewed_products[ $keys[ $post->ID ] ] );
    }

    $viewed_products[] = $post->ID;

    if ( count( $viewed_products ) > 15 ) {
        array_shift( $viewed_products );
    }

    // Store for session only.
    wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', implode( '|', $viewed_products ) );
}

remove_action('template_redirect', 'wc_track_product_view', 20);
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_track_product_view_always', 20 );
```

Comment: Excellent solution Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cookie when you are viewing a single product page so use something like this where I set the cookie to equal the product ID I just viewed.  In your case you'll need to get the cookie value if it exists then append the new product to the list of products.

```
function set_user_visited_product_cookie() {
    global $post;

    if ( is_product() ){
        // manipulate your cookie string here, explode, implode functions
        wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', $post->ID );
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'set_user_visited_product_cookie' );
```

Comment: I have ammended my code to incorporate this. It now works, slightly lol. I can go on and look a 10 products and it now shows me only the first one I viewed.

Comment: Yes I only coded it to save the one product id, your homework is to change it so that it uses the functionality you've already written to append product ID's with a "|" into a string and save it.

Comment: I have looked online and cannot see anything which points me in the right direction. I have tried `if ( is_product() ){
  wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', explode( '|', $post->ID) );
    }` ... and `if ( is_product() ){
  wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', $post->ID, explode( '|', $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed']) );` .... as well as quite a few different variations including `if ( is_product() ){
  wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed', $post->ID, explode( '|', $post->ID, 4) );`    aswell as changing $post->ID to $viewed_products

Answer (score 0):

Below code to set cookie 'woocommerce_recently_viewed' worked for me. Hope it helps other

```
$Existing_product_id = $_COOKIE['woocommerce_recently_viewed'];
if ( is_product() )
{ 
   $updated_product_id = $Existing_product_id.'|'.$post->ID;
   wc_setcookie( 'woocommerce_recently_viewed',  $updated_product_id ); 
}
```